# asp.net dropdownlist error

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu

```
ddlSub.Items.Add(new ListItem("--Select --", ""));
```

gives following error

**cannot convert from 'ListItem' to 'string'**
what is the correct syntax

thanx...

Comment: I think you're missing something here, the `Add` method supports two overloads - `Add(string)` and `Add(ListItem)`. I suspect the error is somewhere else in your code.

Comment: Can you post some more of the code? The line you have referenced above cannot be causing that error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure this is the exact line of code?

I just added a dropdownlist to a webform and then named it the same thing as yours and copy and pasted your line of code into the PageLoad.

```
// in aspx
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSub" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>

// in .cs codebehind
ddlSub.Items.Add(new ListItem("--Select --", ""));
```

Compiles just fine.  You must be leaving something out.

Comment: hey...
thnx for reply..
just missed the System.Web.UI.WebControls in namespaces list...

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue myself by adding `System.Web.UI.WebControls` to the list of namespaces I was importing.

Comment: YOu may want to read the FAQ with StackOverflow.
If your question was answered you need to mark it as answered.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, vote up the answers that you find helpful.

Comment: @kmatyaszek, this answer was from the OP and isn't a 3rd party "thank you" answer =)

Answer (score 0):

It's correct. The error must be when you try to read the value out and expect a ListItem or something similar.

Include more code and we can identify the problem.